# Parallel Solution search

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have written some code in python using multiprocessing package. It sort of searches for a solution for an equation in 6 different ways.So I have 6 different processes running the same function with different parameters. I would like to stop all the sub-processes once the solution has been found by one of the sub-process.Right now after using the join function, the result is that even if the solution is found , the other processes continue , till they find one . I'm using join()  .

```
for i in range(N):
                    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=mysolver,args=(g,h,q,B[i],i,dic,))
                    jobs.append(p)
                    p.start()

            for p in jobs:
                    p.join()
```

This how I call the function for solving. Usually N is 6 -10 .

Comment: `process.join()` will wait for the process to complete, `process.terminate()` might be more useful to you.

Comment: I still want the calling function to wait till one of the processes to complete. Is there a way to do this using only process.terminate() ?

Comment: Post a minimal example of your code so far as a starting point. There should be a way to wait for a result from one of the functions and then kill the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a list containing a reference to all threads and accessible by all threads. This list of threads should be ready before you start the threads. The thread that finds a solution first can kill the others using the list, taking care of not commiting suicide.

You might face a racing condition in case one of the threads dies before you call join. As such you might be calling join on a already dead thread. A quick and dirty workaround is to let each thread wait few milliseconds fot the main thread to call join for all threads.

An other cleaner solution is to use a flag that is checked by all threads while they look for a solution. If they find it to be true, they should immediately terminate by returning. The thread that finds a solution can set the flag to true and return. Now all threads will nicely join the main thread.